# Using object's printed name in script

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to write a script that will end up baking materials from a high poly object to a low poly object. The problem i am having is that i will never know the object names beforehand, as my script is importing obj's from a folder into blender then duplicating them and applying a decimate filter to them. So far i have all of that functioning correctly, but i'm stuck on the final part of selecting the low poly at the target object of the bake.

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='MESH')
{'FINISHED'}

>>> 
>>> for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
...     if obj.name.endswith("001"):
...         print(ob.name)
...         bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
...         
Hat 1.001

>>>
```

I have the script printing out the name of the object that has a name ending in 001 since i know that my low poly duplicate will always end with that. My problem is that i need to take that printed name and apply it to the next command like this example

```
bpy.context.scene.targetobj = "Hat 1.001"
```

I can't figure out how to take the name that gets printed out and apply it like in that example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the name of the object as a string, then store it in a variable. I'm not sure `bpy.context.scene.targetobj` exists though.

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.name.endswith("001"):
        # store the name into a variable
        object_name = obj.name
        # use the variable
        bpy.context.scene.targetobj = object_name
```

Comment: Worked perfectly and I even found a few other spots I could use the name variable, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Use a pointer property**

Can set up a pointer to any blender ID type objects, in this case `bpy.types.Object` instances of which can be found in `bpy.data.objects` collection.

Assign the property to class

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Object, Scene
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


Scene.target_obj = PointerProperty(type=Object)
```

Test.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']

>>> C.scene.target_obj = C.object
>>> C.object.name = "Foo"
>>> C.scene.target_obj
bpy.data.objects['Foo']
```