# Unique and invariable ID (within the session) for an object?

Tags: scripting, objects, add-on

I have tried `print(context.active_object.name_full)`, but that seems to be just the object name that I see in the Outliner. If I change the name in the Outliner, then `name_full` changes, too.

Is there any unique and invariable ID to identify an object at least within the session? That is, the unique ID should not be changed even if the user changes the object's name. The ID does not have to be same if the user opens the file again next time.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170921/15543

Answer (score 3):

**Use a pointer property**

Can set up a pointer to any blender ID type objects, in this case `bpy.types.Object` instances of which can be found in `bpy.data.objects` collection.

Assign the property to class

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Object, Scene
from bpy.props import PointerProperty


Scene.target_obj = PointerProperty(type=Object)
```

Test.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube.001']

>>> C.scene.target_obj = C.object
>>> C.object.name = "Foo"
>>> C.scene.target_obj
bpy.data.objects['Foo']
```

Comment: So this provides a unique way of IDing an object in a scene as long as the scene and object exist in that file? The pointer doesn't change or anything after the file is saved, closed, and reloaded, right?

Comment: Once set it is a reference to that object, or `None` if the object is since removed.

Comment: Thank you - I was all set to generate a UUID for objects, since I know they can be renamed and wanted some handle to be sure I was always using the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my implementation

```
class MYPLUGIN_PROP_uuids(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): #==CollectionProperty
    """bpy.context.scene.myplugin.uuids[i]"""

    uuid : bpy.props.IntProperty()
    owner : bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

class MYPLUGIN_PROP_Scene(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): 
    """bpy.context.scene.myplugin"""

    #need to have a global list where all unique uuid are registered
    uuids : bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MYPLUGIN_PROP_uuids)

def get_uuid(self):
    """generate uuid once on first read"""

    uuids = bpy.context.scene.myplugin.uuids
    uuid = {e.owner:e.uuid for e in uuids}.get(self.id_data)

    if (uuid is None): 

        print("generating uuid..")

        new = uuids.add()
        new.owner = self.id_data
        new.uuid = random.randint(-2_147_483_647,2_147_483_647) 
        #Be Careful, IntPropery has max range >>> ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val:  value not in 'int' range ((-2147483647 - 1), 2147483647)
        #we could make sure generated uuid do not exist already, considering the odds, it is safe to say it is not necessary

        return new.uuid

    return uuid

class MYPLUGIN_PROP_Object(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): 
    """bpy.context.object.myplugin"""
    
    uuid : bpy.props.IntProperty(
        get=get_uuid, 
        description="random id between -2.147.483.647 & 2.147.483.647",
        )
```

when you'll call `bpy.context.object.myplugin.uuid` it will add the identifier to the list on first read, else it will gather the identifier from the list. This implementation supports if users are using ALTD/SHIFTD on your object

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need it for. You could set `object.pass_index` to unique number, or you could create your own custom property:

[image]

Or do it with Python: `object[some_custom_property] = "Some value"`

Comment: if you copy the object the copy will have same pass index and same custom property.