# What's the replacement for id() or hash() on bpy objects?

Tags: python, scripting, properties, vertex-groups

Let's say I have a vertex group layer, that I'd like to identify through the object's lifespan.

In order to identify such bpy object:

- I cannot rely on the name because the users might change it
- I cannot rely on the data contained by the vertex group either, for the same reason.
- I cannot add custom properties because `by.types.VertexGroup` does not support custom properties
- I cannot use `id(my_vglayer)` neither `hash(my_vglayer)` because [how blender handles undo](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#undo-redo) any memory address is therefore un-reliable.
- I cannot store my_vglayer as a global, this might cause crashes, due to changing memory address as explained above.

What am I supposed to do to recognize such a `bpy` object then? It is unfortunate because `id()` or `hash()` was supposed to be stable identifiers working on any kind of python objects...

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/63794345/3466081 work?   Although your hopes may dim with this *old* (2015) posting: https://blenderartists.org/t/can-you-get-a-unique-hash-of-a-blender-object-from-python/655567

Comment: unfortunately, it couldn't work, we'd need to be able to identify the mesh object through it's lifespam, that means also if it's geometry or name change. in the case of mesh object it's quite easy tho we can just add a custom identifier property

Comment: Here's another from devtalk "https://devtalk.blender.org/t/universal-unique-id-per-object/363/4".  Rather ridiculous that there's no UUID technique!

Comment: "just use the name" they said haha

Answer (score 1):

Check out this repo https://github.com/strike-digital/non_id_props by [Strike_Digital](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/57981/strike-digital)
It allows to store reference to non-ID properties similar to blender's PointerProperty. Under the hood it uses blender's msgbus, handlers and python's getter-setter on name of the property to track the it.
I'm guessing They are also using this in their add-ons also.

This is the demo given in the repository

```py
import bpy
from .non_id_props import NonIDProperty


def my_vertex_group_update(self, context):
    print(f"My vertex group is called '{self.my_vertex_group.name if self.my_vertex_group else self.my_vertex_group}'")


class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    # Make sure to assign with an '=' rather than a ':' like other Blender properties
    my_vertex_group = NonIDProperty(
        name="my_vertex_group",  # THIS MUST BE THE SAME AS THE NAME OF THE VARIABLE
        # (Someone please tell me if theres a better way :)
        subtype="vertex_groups",  # This is the path to the non id property, from its parent ID property
        # e.g. object.vertex_groups
        set=my_vertex_group_update,  # The get, set, and update functions work in the same way as default Blender
    )

    # Note that the subtype can only be of a subtype of the ID property this group is registered to
    # (In this case, bpy.types.Object)
    my_modifier = NonIDProperty(
        name="my_modifier",
        subtype="modifiers",
    )

    my_constraint = NonIDProperty(
        name="my_constraint",
        subtype="constraints",
    )


classes = [MyPropertyGroup]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.non_id_prop_demo = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    del bpy.types.Scene.non_id_prop_demo
```

I would like to invite you to BPY discord server: https://discord.gg/dRvw2yNHGv
where this was shared by them. It is a community focused on blender add-on development and Blender's python api

Comment: I was hoping for a more low-level solution, but well it seems that there is no other solutions

Answer (score 0):

I presented a homemade implementation of integer `uuid` for objects types in this topic
[Unique and invariable ID (within the session) for an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183635/unique-and-invariable-id-within-the-session-for-an-object/273770#273770)